Polynomial Multivariate Regression Setup
I have a formula (Y = x1 + Ax1^2 + Bx2^2 + Cx3^2 + Constant), and a dataset to train the model.
The dataset includes a column for each Y, x1, x2, x3, and the Month.
I'd like the regression analysis to run 12 times, once for each Month - such that I'll be able to see a table of 12 rows (one for each month) with coefficients and constants to reference for calculating predictions.
For an initial test (without monthly granularity), I attempted to run the following code: I was surprised when I reviewed the model.coef_ that the output was an array with 10 numbers in it, which seemed strange to me as I only defined three x variables.
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

    #Read dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

    #Replace negative y with zero
    dataset.x1[dataset.y<0]=0

    #define x and y
    X = dataset[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']].values
    y = dataset['y'].values

    # Polynomial Features
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
    X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

    # Linear Regression model
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_poly, y)


Look like you get the parameters for the model a1 * x1**2 + a2 * x2**2 + a3 * x3**2 + a4 * x1 * x2 + a5 * x1 * x3 + a6 * x2 * x3 + a7 * x1 + a8 * x2 + a9 * x3 + a10

See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#polynomial-features

You can define a row and use _append(row, ignore_index=True):
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

np.random.seed(7)


def _reg(df):
    df['y'] = df['y'].apply(lambda x: max(0, x))
    res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Month', 'Intercept', 'x1', 'x1^2', 'x2', 'x2^2', 'x3', 'x3^2'])

    for month in range(1, 12 + 1):
        MD = df[df['Month'] == month]
        X = MD[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']].values
        y = MD['y'].values

        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
        X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(X_poly, y)

        C, I = model.coef_, model.intercept_

        row = {
            'Month': month,
            'Intercept': I,
            'x1': C[0],
            'x1^2': C[1],
            'x2': C[2],
            'x2^2': C[3],
            'x3': C[4],
            'x3^2': C[5]
        }

        res = res._append(row, ignore_index=True)

    return res


D = {
    'Month': np.tile(np.arange(1, 12 + 1), 10),
    'x1': np.random.rand(120),
    'x2': np.random.rand(120),
    'x3': np.random.rand(120),
    'y': np.random.rand(120) * 100
}

print(_reg(pd.DataFrame(D)))




Month     Intercept            x1          x1^2            x2         x2^2            x3          x3^2
0     1.0   -396.685864   -838.355005   1977.924774    166.926094   943.923511   -141.168999    456.339836
1     2.0    701.123436    -27.728075  -1314.896489  -1428.443874   101.653099   -141.863661   -190.242231
2     3.0     38.685648    169.333769   -167.182977     65.880045     2.041339   -130.442369   -160.386682
3     4.0  11520.520160 -20693.204637 -29086.468139 -20283.355062  5441.143347  33330.983453  14407.203117
4     5.0    592.393075  -1685.339857   1086.255420   -715.940115  1245.087653  -1027.804520    481.857854
5     6.0   -233.314216   1240.412948    205.030238    -57.587846 -1136.591038   -593.707599   -216.160353
6     7.0    400.945394    185.761413   -364.327447  -1815.975397  -486.872946     29.063005    754.256055
7     8.0  -1140.482971    852.017914   2979.596187   -268.551305   -74.497015  -1216.717308    229.281570
8     9.0    348.349208    560.117586    952.125489  -2367.337084   -77.373536   1130.451671  -2052.721441
9    10.0   -334.411159    736.157153   1042.062772   -649.205983  -238.716755   -986.771396    381.462013
10   11.0     99.660329 -15917.820009  34562.718307   1887.453411  6973.614364 -13404.560348  14357.496546
11   12.0    168.798486    514.097439   -382.697454   -187.672120  -451.309680     89.495793   -444.866136


Notes:

Intercept is the intercept term of the regression equation, which is the value of the dependent variable (y) when all independent variables (x1, x2, x3) are zero, or the base value of y.

x1, x2, x3 are the coefficients of the linear terms for the independent variables x1, x2, and x3, which are the changes in the dependent variable (y) for a one-unit change in each independent variable, keeping all other variables constant.

x1^2, x2^2, x3^2 are the coefficients of the quadratic terms for the independent variables x1, x2, and x3, which are the changes in the dependent variable (y) for a one-unit change in each independent variable squared, while keeping all other variables constant.



Thanks for clarifying the columns.  I'm confused about the the dictionary "D" - you've coded it to generate random numbers rather than pull the coefficients from the model runs.  Am I right?  When I run it with your code it's giving me different values each time because of the random number generation.  Assuming that you start with my dataset (df) with random numbers generated, how would I pull the Dictionary view to show actual model coefficients?

@PatrickFlume Add a seed: np.random.seed(42). You can also use this code, modify it with your actual data, then post new questions (one by one), if you had any problems. You can just a partial of your current dataset in your new questions.

Thanks @user24714692 - I've posted with dataset slice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78653994/polynomial-multivariate-regression-analysis-2?noredirect=1#comment138671448_78653994
