Polynomial Multivariate Regression Analysis 2
I'm new to regression analysis in python and greatly appreciate your help:
I have a formula (Y = x1 + Ax1^2 + Bx2^2 + Cx3^2 + Constant), and a dataset to train the model. The dataset includes a column for each Y, x1, x2, x3, and the Month. See example dataset here
I'd like the regression analysis to run 12 times, once for each Month - such that I'll be able to see a table of 12 rows (one for each month) with coefficients and constants to reference for calculating predictions.
Presently I have the following code set up which does not present the modelrun coefficients and intercepts by month.  Can someone help me add to the code to present a table of coefficients and constants, one row for each month?

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('StackOverdlow - Example Dataset 20240621.csv')

#Replace negative y with zero
df.y[df.y<0]=0


def _reg(df):
    df['y'] = df['y'].apply(lambda x: max(0, x))
    res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Month', 'Intercept', 'x1', 'x1^2', 'x2', 'x2^2', 'x3', 'x3^2'])

    for month in range(1, 12 + 1):
        MD = df[df['Month'] == month]
        X = MD[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']].values
        y = MD['y'].values

        poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
        X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(X_poly, y)

        C, I = model.coef_, model.intercept_

        row = {
            'Month': month,
            'Intercept': I,
            'x1': C[0],
            'x1^2': C[1],
            'x2': C[2],
            'x2^2': C[3],
            'x3': C[4],
            'x3^2': C[5]
        }

        res = res._append(row, ignore_index=True)

    return res

I tried the above code with the following recommended code appended and it does not pull the actual coefficients from the model run.

D = {
    'Month': np.tile(np.arange(1, 12 + 1), 10),
    'x1': np.random.rand(120),
    'x2': np.random.rand(120),
    'x3': np.random.rand(120),
    'y': np.random.rand(120) * 100
}

print(_reg(pd.DataFrame(D)))


Why is month not a regressor?

@walkrflocka Each month be its own model with its own set of coefficients.

Is this what you want?

Yes I believe so, I should be able to save the print(_reg(df)) unto its own data frame and run predictions from that.  Excellent!

@PatrickFlume I'm asking, why do you want to do this - it's much cleaner to just add it as a regressor. Are you expecting there to be interaction terms between month and x1...xn? If you are, why not add those interaction terms explicitly? If you aren't, why not just add month if you're certain it won't alter the coefficients?

@walkrflocka : for general purpose model (like neural networks, that, if they are deep enough, can represent any function), that would be probably a good suggestion to use month as an input variable, rather than separating months. For for a linear regression, that is not the same. Nothing says that the difference between months can be linearly computed by having the same coefficient for all xᵢ² terms, and adding some α.month to that.

@chrslg You’re correct, but in a practical sense linearity assumptions will really never be perfectly fulfilled with real world data except in certain narrow cases - but as long as your RMSE targets get hit… super good enough. Besides, it’s worth testing to see if it could be modeled cleanly with the inclusion of a date regressor - maybe it would! No use in immediately assuming you can’t.

Use only features you want for regression
But, unless I miss something, you are not doing the right regression.
What you are computing are coefficients α,β,γ,δ,η,κ,λ,μ,φ such as
Y ≈ α.x₁ + δ.x₁² + η.x₂² + κ.x₃² ( so far, so good)
 + β.x₂ + γ.x₃ + λ.x₁.x₂ + μ.x₁.x₃ + φ.x₂.x₃ (that you don't want)
Polynomials features gives you all monomial of degree 2 or less. That includes xᵢ.xⱼ like monomial (degree 2, but not the one you want), and xᵢ like monomial (degree 1, that you don't want, except maybe for x1).
Just doing that regression, and then not using the matching coefficients (that is ignoring λ, μ and φ in my notation) is not a way to do the regression on only the monomial you want. The fact that your compute λ, μ, φ makes α, β, ... false if you use them without the 3 ignored terms.
Simplified example. Imagine that I have the following data



x
y
f(x,y)




2
1
5


1
2
5


1
1
3



If I search for a formula "f(x,y) = a.x + b.y + c.x.y", then an exact (so unbeatable) solution is "f(x,y) = x+y+xy"
But if I compute the regression with the 3rd column and then ignore the xy term, I get "f(x,y)≈x+y", so "3,3,2" instead of "5,5,3".
That is not exact, of course (but that the point of regressions: finding approximate solutions when no exact one exist). But that is not the best approximation. If I compute the regression with only 2 columns, I get a better approximation (and the best one), that is "f(x,Y)=18(x+y)/11", so "4.91, 4.91, 3.27". Which, as you can at one glance see, is a way better approximation of "5,5,3" than "3,3,2".
So, point is, you can't compute a regression against a given set a features by computing a regression against a bigger set of features and then just ignoring the coefficient you don't want.
Solution
Either you insist on using PolynomialFeatures. But then, after the poly.fit_transform, you need to select only the relevant columns.
X_poly = X_poly[:, [0,3,6,8]]

Or you compute directly those features yourself.
X_poly = np.empty((len(X), 4))
X_poly[:,0] = X[:,0]
X_poly[:,1] = X[:,0]**2
X_poly[:,2] = X[:,1]**2
X_poly[:,3] = X[:,2]**2

Case of x1
Unless this was just a typo, the formula you gave doesn't have a coefficient for x1 (or, more accurately, it has a coefficient 1. But point is, you don't want to compute a coefficient for x1, since you've already chosen it to be 1).
So, you should try then to do a linear regression of
y-x₁ = Ax₁² + Bx₂² + Cx₃² + Constant
So
X_poly = np.empty((len(X), 3))
X_poly[:,1] = X[:,0]**2
X_poly[:,2] = X[:,1]**2
X_poly[:,3] = X[:,2]**2
# Or, in this very case, that could be just
X_poly = X**2

Y_poly = Y-X[:,0]
# And then
model.fit(X_poly, Y_poly)

Edit after comment
Look at what you have in X_poly.
X=np.array([[1,2,2], [2,2,3], [3,4,5], [4,2,1]])
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
print(X_poly.shape)
# (4,9)... 9 colums, when you wanted only 4 (or 6)
print(X_poly)
#array([[ 1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
#       [ 2.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  6.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
#       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  9., 12., 15., 16., 20., 25.],
#       [ 4.,  2.,  1., 16.,  8.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  1.]])
# Obviously columns are
# x1, x2, x3, x1², x1.x2, x1.x3, x2², x2.x3, x3²
# Which is anyway explicitly said here
poly.get_feature_names_out()
# array(['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x0^2', 'x0 x1', 'x0 x2', 'x1^2', 'x1 x2',
#       'x2^2'], dtype=object)

With this X_poly, you can only get a formula Y=Ax1 + Bx2 + Cx3 + Dx1² + Ex1x2 + Fx1x3 + Gx2² + Hx2x3 + Ix3².
Those coefficients being what is in model.coef_ after linear regression
model.fit(X_poly, y)
model.coef_
#array([ 0.21769754, -0.05785195,  0.04790529,  0.80654007,  0.26183922,
#        0.37399458, -0.3471117 , -0.19344918,  0.13640372])

As you can see, 9 coefficients, not 6 or 4.
And if you don't use all 9, the one you use are meaningless.
And even worse (I missed that earlier), the one you use are the 6 first. So, what you call x1 (C[0]), x1² (C[1]), x2 (C[2]), x2² (C[3]), x3 (C[4]) and x3² (C[5]) are in reality coefficients for x1, x2, x3, x1², x1*x2, x1*x3, in that order!
Even if you had used C[0], C[3], C[1], C[6], C[2], C[8] in that order for x1,x1^2,x2,x2^2,x3,x3^2, which would have been the correct meaning of those coefficients, they would have been only valid along the 3 unused ones. But in addition, you mixed them.
My version of your code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Read dataset - just an example
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Month":np.random.randint(1,13,1000), "x1":np.random.rand(1000), "x2":np.random.rand(1000), "x3":np.random.rand(1000), "y":np.random.rand(1000)})

def _reg(df):

    res=[]
    # avoid using numpy array or pandas dataframe when you intend to increse them row by row.
    # it is more efficient to use a good old plain python list, and turn it into a dataframe only at the end

    for month in range(1, 12 + 1):
        MD = df[df['Month'] == month]
        X = MD[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']].values
        y = MD['y'].values

        X_poly=np.empty((len(X), 4))
        X_poly[:,0] = X[:,0] # x1
        X_poly[:,1] = X[:,0]**2 # x1²
        X_poly[:,2] = X[:,1]**2 # x2²
        X_poly[:,3] = X[:,2]**2 # x3²

        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(X_poly, y)

        C, I = model.coef_, model.intercept_
        res.append([month, I] + C.tolist())

    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Month', 'Intercept', 'x₁', 'x₁²', 'x₂²', 'x₃²'])

print(_reg(df))

Result is
    Month  Intercept        x₁       x₁²       x₂²       x₃²
0       1   0.374436  0.764512 -0.687949 -0.059733 -0.087113
1       2   0.527972 -0.246341  0.362714 -0.008101 -0.109076
2       3   0.344394  0.541543 -0.566065  0.151740 -0.072334
3       4   0.629204 -0.221336  0.263586 -0.086742 -0.039182
4       5   0.570995  0.216032 -0.195416 -0.199324 -0.132590
5       6   0.461338 -0.042120 -0.003289 -0.006292 -0.003541
6       7   0.170754  1.478999 -1.534895  0.171295  0.087295
7       8   0.558349 -0.077344 -0.042258 -0.177389  0.100142
8       9   0.314804  0.680844 -0.590113  0.051441  0.089870
9      10   0.415270  1.189805 -1.297864 -0.246226 -0.013459
10     11   0.403131  0.136644 -0.112428  0.062625 -0.004009
11     12   0.469749 -0.016211  0.186827  0.000330  0.056927


Hi @chrslg - I do want the coefficient to x1 as well as x1^2 (typo).  I understand your point, and it's well taken, I don't need coefficients for the terms x2 and x3 - I was planning to reassess once I got the code working correctly.  I've taken user24714692's code from the comments and adjusted it per your recommendation.  Could you take a look to see if I've addressed your concerns?  https://ideone.com/e.js/pQ0kL7

@PatrickFlume : no, you haven't. Look at what you get in X_poly. You have way more columns that you need. Since you want to compute 4 coefficients (plus intercept), your X for linear regression should have 4 columns. Job of linear regression is to find the best A,B,C,D such as A*Col1 + B*Col2 + C*Col3 + D*Col4 ≈ Y. if you have extra columns Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9 in X, it will compute extra coefficient, E,F,G,H,I and J. And A,B,C,D will be irrelevant if you ignore those 5 extra terms. Which you do.

@PatrickFlume as far as I understand, what you did is just removing some columns from your result (the one for x2, x3). But that wasn't my point. I have no opinion on which coefficient you should be interested in (that is related to your application context). My point is "if you are interested in coefficients for x1, x1²,x2²,x³ terms, then you should have only x1, x1², x2², x3² in the X_poly you provide to the linear regression model". "If you are interested in coefficients for x1, x2,x3, x1²,x2²,x3² terms, then you should have onl; x1,x2,x3,x1²,x2²,x3² colums in that X_poly"

Whether it is the first on second version of those 2 sentences that match your case doesn't matter. What is important is that X_poly contains only what you need, and nothing else. What you've changes is passing from the second version (6 coefficients computed) to the first version (4 coefficients computed), which, really, doesn't matter (it is up to you to choose the one you prefer). But in both case, you passed a X_poly that have neither 6 nor 4 columns, but 9 columns. That is 3 to 5 extra columns. 3 to 5 extra coefficient computed by linear regression. That you choose to ignor

afterward, but that were part of the computation, and without which the other 4 to 6 computer coefficients are false.

So bottom line is, even if you solve your form problem (how to have an array of coefficient  per month), what will be in this array would be false coefficients. In both versions of your code.
